# How can I $sum a decimal field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, azure, aggregation-framework, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using Azure Cosmos MongoDB. Given some sample data where we can assume that the amount field actually contains `Decimal128` values, how can I sum it in an aggregation?

```
{ amount: 1.23 }
{ amount: 4.56 }
```

When I simply do it like so:

```
data.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalAmount: { $sum: "$amount" }
    }
  }
])
```

It seems to either return 0 or an error about expecting an integer.

Comment: Could you provide some details? Version of the database, client, and error message? It works there https://mongoplayground.net/p/p98gXYa0Rjv  What do you mean by "either" ?  is the aggregation not consistent or do you change something to get different results?

Comment: So it does, I am even exporting my pipeline into that and its working as expected. I am using Azure Cosmos MongoDB and like I said it is either returning 0 or "Expected an integer type. Found : decimal". If I add a `$limit: 10` into the pipeline then it returns 0 but if I do the full collection then it returns the error, which makes me think some of the documents don't have decimals in them. But still even with just 10 decimal values it returns 0 instead of the actual value. All the values are positive values gt 100, so it shouldn't be 0.

Comment: If I change it to `totalAmount: { $sum: { $toDouble: "$amount" } },` then it works, but of course it's a double not a decimal and there appears to be floating point error in the result.

Comment: How did you create the table? using a datashseet view?

Comment: "which makes me think some of the documents ..." - yep, it's quite common for documents to have unexpected data. Try `[{"$project": {amount_type: {$type: "$amount"}}},{$group: {_id: "$amount_type"}}]` pipeline to understand your data.

Comment: Please be sure to put additional details in your question, not as comments (especially important when including code/queries that have formatted text)

Comment: After looking at this extensively it appears to that cosmosdb is simply unable to sum decimals. After doing some trickery to convert the decimals I can also see that mongodb appears to be casting all sums into an int32 and will overflow if you have a lot of data. 

There seems to be a bug/limitation in cosmos which will always convert your sum into an int32 at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `$toDecimal`, the sum is correct, however, it comes with trailing zeroes.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalAmount: {
        $sum: {
          "$toDecimal": "$amount"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1w1BnjbDnR3).

Comment: Thank you, this is right but it doesn't work in cosmosdb. I should have put that in the title but it is in the question body.

Comment: Ohh okk, I missed it.